# Same app or two different apps Frontend/Backend App on Meanstack using Angular4, Express and Mongo?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, mean-stack

I am an experienced PHP developer and new to NodeJs and Angular. I have been learning these things from last 3-4 months. Now i know basics of Nodejs, Express, Angular4, Socket.io and meanstack.

I have created demo apps like authentication app in nodejs, Simple chat using node and socket. simple crud application in meanstack during my learning phase

Now i am about to start on a big project, something like a portal. Which will have "frontend for users" and "backend for admin"

Now question is 
1) should i create two different app for backend and frontend hosted on same server on different ports(Say,. frontend on port 80 and backend on port 81) and connected to same database. or should i create both on same app and run backend on url like `domain.com/admin`.

I am asking to know that what other developers do while creating such big project on meanstack. do they use same app or two different apps

2) I don't find any way to create two different template for frontend and backend on one Angular CLI project. as there is one `index.html` file in `src/` folder where we can define our components and template structure.

So is there any reference how to create two templates in same angular cli app.

Any kind of help will be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**App.routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    loadChildren: './client/client.route.module#ClientRouteModule'
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.route.module#AdminRouteModule'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

You can create two different folder admin and frontend or client. and do Seperate routing for both admin and client.

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on whether you want to abstract your back end application out for reuse with other front end apps, or whether you want to create one integrated piece.

I would opt for the former, more modular approach, and implement it like this:

1. Two separate apps. Neither of these would talk to database directly, but they would instead interact with endpoints that you expose through Express.
2. Through Express routing, I would define front end routes for `/` and
   back end routes for `/admin`. These would effectively hit two
   separate Angular applications.

If, however, you choose to go with just one app, [Angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jorge. I was also thinking of same. create two different apps for frontend and backend and let them talk through APIs created using express. In this way i can add more panel in future if required.